# Does $x-x^2+x^2-x^2+x^2 - \dots=\frac14 x^2$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, solution-verification, power-series

The following is just some context; you don't need to read it.

I had to find the locus of P(x,y) when x=2t and y=2t-t<sup>2</sup>. I went about solving it, but I stumbled upon:

> x=2t
> y=2t-t<sup>2</sup>
> y=x-t<sup>2</sup>
> y=x-x<sup>2</sup>+3t<sup>2</sup>
> y=x-x<sup>2</sup>+x<sup>2</sup>-t<sup>2</sup>
> y=x-x<sup>2</sup>+x<sup>2</sup>-x<sup>2</sup>+3t<sup>2</sup>
> ...
> y=x-x<sup>2</sup>+x<sup>2</sup>-x<sup>2</sup>+x<sup>2</sup>...

I knew this was wrong because none of the previous answers looked like this, so I tried it again.

> x=2t
> y=2t-t<sup>2</sup>
> y=x-t<sup>2</sup>
> y=x-x<sup>2</sup>/4

Instead of adding and subtracting, I divided for this attempt. I thought, were both my attempts correct in some sense? My steps seemed correct, and I don't think I divided by zero in any step. Does this mean x-x<sup>2</sup>+x<sup>2</sup>-x<sup>2</sup>+x<sup>2</sup>=x-x<sup>2</sup>/4?

Comment: This makes no sense. The infinite sum $a -a + a -a + \cdots$ is undefined. The finite sum is either $0$ or $a$ depending on whether you have an even or an odd number of terms. If you want more help, [edit] the question and use mathjax formatting. https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference  Don't try to respond with a comment. Hint: plot some points on this parametric curve before you play with algebra.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first approach is correct (though not that useful); but you make a mistake by extrapolating from your finite series to an infinite series.  You correctly derived the following family of equations:
$$
\begin{eqnarray}
y &=& x-t^2 \\
y &=& x-x^2+3t^2 \\
y &=& x-x^2+x^2-t^2 \\
y &=& x-x^2+x^2-x^2+3t^2 \\
y &=& x-x^2+x^2-x^2+x^2-t^2 \\
&\cdots&
\end{eqnarray}
$$
But you can't go from these to $y=x-x^2+x^2-x^2+x^2-\ldots$.  The final term, since it's not becoming smaller with each equation, still matters!  In fact, since $-x^2+x^2$ can be cancelled when it appears, you really only have two distinct equations, the first two.  Those can both be correct only if $-t^2=-x^2+3t^2$, or $t^2=x^2/4$; and then each reduces to the same answer as your second approach, $y=x-x^2/4$.

Comment: Note that it's also true, as a commenter on the original question points out, that $-x^2+x^2-x^2+x^2-x^2+\ldots$ is not a convergent series, and so is "meaningless" in a formal sense.  But the key issue here is that the term being dropped ($-t^2$ or $3t^2$) isn't negligible in any sense.  If you can correctly derive $y=a_1+\epsilon_1$, and $y=a_1+a_2+\epsilon_2$, and $y=a_1+a_2+a_3+\epsilon_3$, etc... then you *can*, in fact, say that $y=\sum_i a_i$, provided only that $\epsilon_i \rightarrow 0$.